# Azure ACS endpoint for US gov cloud

Tags: azure-gov, azure-acs

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/extending-sharepoint-online-for-germany-china-usgovernment-environments#azure-acs-endpoints) page states endpoint for Azure ACS for US gov is https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/ but this does not work and throws error AADSTS900382: Confidential Client is not supported in Cross Cloud request

Looking for a confirmation whether the correct one is https://login.microsoftonline.us/?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/extending-sharepoint-online-for-germany-china-usgovernment-environments#azure-acs-endpoints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed with Microsoft, this document is outdated and the updated endpoint for Azure ACS for US Gov cloud is https://login.microsoftonline.us/